# confidence interval plot for time series R code?

Tags: r, time-series

I want to plot time series predictions and confidence interval using arima model in R. Here is the code:

```
library(forecast)

fit <- auto.arima(ldeaths)

pred <- forecast(fit, h=12, level=0.95)

library(dygraphs)

dygraph(cbind(ldeaths, pred$lower, pred$mean, pred$upper), 
    main = "Deaths from Lung Disease (UK)") %>%
    dySeries("ldeaths", label = "Actual") %>%
    dySeries(c("pred$lower", "pred$mean", "pred$upper"), 
     label = "Predicted", fill = "red")
```

Is it correct and logical? Is the prediction and confidence interval actually being shown?

Comment: Yes, I have run the code it is working fine.

Comment: thx! i am worried that maybe this is not the real prediction and confidence interval.